# Java Producer Consumer 1 - N threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to have a producer thread that would fetch from a web server new jobs. These should be stored at a local storage as queue or in memory . Then there should be a consumer thread that would read from queue and send these data over rs232 serial. Only one consumer per serial interface as it doesnt make sense otherwise. The problem is how can consumer thread be notified while it is communicating with rs232 ?

Comment: Why `N` consumers? Do you have several serial ports? Either way, it's not exactly clear, what is problem at hand.

Comment: I don't get it: why would you want to notify the consumer thread while it is communicating with rs232? isn't it supposed to 1) wait until the queue is not empty, 2) get next item from queue and send it through rs232?

Comment: yes there might be 2 serial ports. @MauricePerry yes it should wait. But I want it to be reliable. I didnt know BlockingQueue.  The key is that 'wait if there is nothing in queue'.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the concurrent package.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

One of the collections in there will most likely meet your needs.

The consumer threads just pull data off the queue as they are ready to process it.